# HTML tag span goes outside for tags search result extended by user parameter

Tags: bug, tags

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%20user%3Ame) for example:

> [image: span class]

This affects at least Stack Overflow on Russian too.

[Same here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bquestions%5D%20user%3Ame):

> [image: mse]

It seems it happen when the tag description contains the tag name itself.